# forEach() loop in protractor to test language changes

Tags: typescript, foreach, protractor

how can I format the following code in a Page Object model to cycle through all available display languages on a webpage:

in the Page object

```
languageBulgarian = element(by.css('.vm-language-choices > li:nth-child(1)'));
loginButtonTextBulgarian = 'XXX';
aboutTextBulgarian = 'XXX';
languageCzech = element(by.css('.vm-language-choices > li:nth-child(2)'));
loginButtonTextCzech = 'Prihlaseni';
aboutTextCzech = 'O';
languageDanish = element(by.css('.vm-language-choices > li:nth-child(3)'));
loginButtonTextDanish = 'Log ind';
aboutTextDanish = 'Om';
```

etc...

in the spec file, I am testing:

```
it('should change the language to Czech when selected from the language drop-down', () => {
  loginPage.clickLanguageDropdown();
  loginPage.languageCzech.click();
  loginPage.waitForElementText(loginPage.loginButton, loginPage.loginButtonTextCzech);
  loginPage.waitForElementText(loginPage.aboutHeader, loginPage.aboutTextCzech);
  expect(loginPage.loginButton.getText()).toEqual(loginPage.loginButtonTextCzech);
  expect(loginPage.aboutHeader.getText()).toEqual(loginPage.aboutTextCzech);
});
```

I want to move this function into a page object helper function and iterate through the languages in an Array using forEach.  I'm just so new I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all your languages and expected text as objects in an array. Then iterate over the array with forEach. Since the `languageBulgarian` element only changes by the number of the nth-child, you can use the array index for that, and don't even need to store any additional page objects.

```
it('should change the language when selected from the language drop-down', () => {
    var languages = [
        {name: 'Bulgarian', login: 'XXX', about: 'XXX'},
        {name: 'Czech', login: 'Prihlaseni', about: 'O'}
    ];

    languages.forEach((language, i) => {
        loginPage.clickLanguageDropdown();
        loginPage.element(by.css('.vm-language-choices > li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').click();
        expect(loginPage.loginButton.getText()).toEqual(languages[i].login);
        expect(loginPage.aboutHeader.getText()).toEqual(languages[i].about);
    });
});
```